# Fix animation lag and wait time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a posts masonry wall with 2 arrows that move to the right and the left.

This is my code below:

```
$next.click(function() {
  $car.scrollTo($('.next-target'), 1000, {
    easing: 'easeOutCubic', 
    axis: 'x'
  });
  return false;
});

$prev.click(function() {
  $car.scrollTo($('.prev-target').last(), 1000, {
    easing: 'easeOutCubic', 
    axis: 'x'
  });
  return false;
});
```

The current animation works but if you click twice fast, the animation lags and only executes once.

What should I change so that when you click twice, it moves twice even if the animation is not done?

Comment: May be add click counter and add callback to decrement counter once scroll done and loop scrollTo till counter reset back to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the animation is active.
So what i have done, is having a Var working as a Boolean to check if the animation is active, and then after 500ms make it possible to do the animation again.

```
   var isAnimating = false;
    $next.click(function() {
     if(!isAnimating){
       isAnimating = true;
       $car.scrollTo($('.next-target'), 0, {
         easing: 'easeOutCubic', 
         axis: 'x'
       });
     }
    setTimeout(function(){ isAnimating = false; }, 500);
    });

    $prev.click(function() {
      $car.scrollTo($('.prev-target').last(), 0, {
     if(!isAnimating){
       isAnimating = true;
        easing: 'easeOutCubic', 
        axis: 'x'
      });
     }
    setTimeout(function(){ isAnimating = false; }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it so that if you click while the animation is active, another animation is counted and starts right after the first one is done?